# How to hide all elements on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have piece of code which hides all odd and even elements in the list i require apart from first two elements i would like to hide other 4 elements. Here is my piece of code:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>White</li>
        <li>Carrots</li>
        <li>Orange</li>
        <li>Broccoli</li>
        <li>Green</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $( "li" )
            .filter( ":odd" )
            .hide()
            .end()
            .filter( ":even" )
            .hover(function() {
                $( this )
                    .toggleClass( "active" )
                    .next()
                    .stop( true, true )
                    .slideToggle();
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

Suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

use **[gt() selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** to achieve it:

```
$( "li:gt(1)" )
.filter( ":odd" )
.hide()
.end()
.filter( ":even" )
.hover(function() {
  $( this )
    .toggleClass( "active" )
    .next()
      .stop( true, true )
      .slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/88EG3/)

Read more about [**gt() here**](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('.MainUl').find('li:first').hover(function() {
     $('.MainUl').find('li').not($(this)).not($(this).next("li")).hide();
 });

 $('.MainUl').find('li:first').next("li").hover(function() {
     $('.MainUl').find('li').not($(this)).not($(this).prev("li")).hide();
 });
```

Fiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/gT2H6/1/